# batch file in windows not calling the php file

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I'am trying to call a php file via batch file in windows.

I tried something like

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\feedback\cron_job.php
```

and also

```
@echo OFF
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" C:\xampp\htdocs\feedback\cron_job.php %*
```

If I run this batch file, a command prompt opens but the script is not executing and I don't get any errors, should I set php path in environment variables? Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: got worked after using WGET library instead @double-beep

Comment: What do you mean exactly with that? What did you do?

Comment: i have installed wget library and added the following code in .bat file  "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/Flyspray/mailnotification.php

Comment: Then please remove your question or if you can't flag it for moderation atention.

Comment: this discussion will help for someone in future know? are you sure should i remove?

Answer (score 1):

You must set php folder to `PATH` in environment variables (user and system) and everything ok

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. When you earn sufficient reputation you will comment on other people's posts.